# Traefik 2 how to refer tls certificates inside static config for routing inside docker-compose files

Tags: docker, traefik

I've defined a static configuration for in my `traefik_v2.yml`

```
api: 
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true
global: {}
providers:
  providersThrottleDuration: 2s
  docker:
    watch: true
    endpoint: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    swarmModeRefreshSeconds: 15s
  file:
    filename: "traefik_v2.yml"
log:
  level: INFO
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /run/secrets/cert_secret
      keyFile: /run/secrets/cert_key_secret
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
    redirections:
      entrypoint:
        to: external
        scheme: https
  web-secure:
    address: ":443"
  api:
    address: ":8080"
  external:
    address: ":10443"
```

Now in one of my compose files, how can I configure the router tls configs to the ones existent in the static file `traefik_v2.yml` ?

```
    version: '3.4'

    services:

      x-authentication-app:
        image: x_authentication_app_nightly:v${BUILD_NUMBER}
        deploy:
          labels:
            - "traefik.docker.network=x-swarm-net"
            - "traefik.http.routers.authenticationapp.rule=PathPrefix(`/authentication`)"    
            - "traefik.http.routers.authenticationapp.service=x-authentication-app"    
            - "traefik.http.routers.authenticationapp.entrypoints=web"   
            - "traefik.http.routers.authenticationapp.tls={}" // **What to say in here ? I want to use the static configurations that I created for tls in the traefik_v2.yml**
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.port=80"
          replicas: 1
          update_config:
            parallelism: 1
            delay: 10s
            order: stop-first
        networks:
          - default

    networks:
      default:
        external:
          name: x-swarm-net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to say anything else juste set `traefik.http.routers.authenticationapp.tls=true`.

You also need to make your endpoint listen on port 443:

`traefik.http.routers.authenticationapp.entrypoints=web, web-secure`

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try it out. Also, is it necessary to specify the Host in the routing rules ? Never did it when using traefik v1

Comment: I don't think so but I'm not sure about that.